# SED to replace spaces in certain position

Tags: sed, solaris

I have a requirement as below.

data.txt

```
12345678909876456   qwerty
1234567890987       qwerty
23456789011234567   qwerty
```

I want to show it in the below way.

```
It will replace from 11th position to 20th position.
It will replace all spaces with '0' in between that position.
And it should consider only replace line starts with 1234.
```

Expected Output:

```
12345678900009876456qwerty
12345678900000000987qwerty
23456789011234567   qwerty
```

So far I am able to tokenize the string but not able to replace spaces properly.

```
sed 's/^1234\(.\{6\}\)\(.\{10\}\)\(.*\)/1234\1Hi\3/' data.txt
```

its giving me output as

```
1234567890Hiqwerty
1234567890Hiqwerty
23456789011234567   qwerty
```

Comment: Your expected output seems wrong. There are 4 spaces on the first line, why are only 3 zeros expected? The last line starts with `234`, why are spaces replaced with zeros?

Comment: 1st line has one extra space. But I am unable to replace all spaces to 0 in all lines.

Comment: At first, I thought you need something like `sed -E '/^1234/{:a;s/(.{11,19})[[:blank:]]/\10/; ta}' file`.

Comment: Now, try `sed -E '/^1234/{:a;s/(.{10})(.{0,10}[^[:blank:]])[[:blank:]]/\10\2/; ta}' file`

Comment: You are correct, I edited my question again. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Not working with sed -E '/^1234/{:a;s/(.{10})(.{0,10}[^[:blank:]])[[:blank:]]/\10\2/; ta}' file. Giving me error as Label too long: /^1234/{:a;s/(.{10})(.{0,10}[^[:blank:]])[[:blank:]]/\10\2/; ta}

Comment: What is the OS? Try `sed -E -e '/^1234/{' -e :a -e 's/^(.{10})(.{0,10}[^[:blank:]])[[:blank:]]/\10\2/' -e ta -e '}' file`. Or, a POSIX BRE, `sed -e '/^1234/{' -e :a -e 's/^\(.\{10\}\)\(.\{0,10\}[^[:blank:]]\)[[:blank:]]/\10\2/' -e ta -e '}' file`

Comment: The OS is Solaris.

Comment: @ChiranjitPaul: Which version of Solaris?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Awk for this instead.

```sh
awk '/^1234/ {
    head = substr($0, 1, 10)
    mid = substr($0, 11, 9)
    tail = substr($0, 21)
    sub(/ /, "0", mid)
    printf("%s%s%s\n", head, mid, tail)
    next }1' file
```

The above implements the logic you specified in the prose, but the output doesn't match your desired output. I'm guessing you really mean

```
awk '/^1234/ {
    head = substr($0, 1, 10)
    mid = substr($0, 11, 9)
    tail = substr($0, 21)
    sub(/ *$/, "", mid)
    printf("%s%-010.10i%s\n", head, mid, tail)
    next }1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You added a `sed` tag so here goes.

Cannot test on Solaris but staying on the straight and narrow with
GNU sed 4.7 the desired output is produced by following script which
right-aligns and zero-pads non-space characters in positions 11-20
incl. in lines beginning with '1234'.

```
LC_CTYPE=POSIX  POSIXLY_CORRECT=1  sed --posix '
/^1234......\(.\{10\}\).*/ !b
h
s//\1/
s/\([^ ]*\)\([ ]*\)/\2\1/
y/ /0/
x
G
s/^\(.\{10\}\)\(.\{10\}\)\(.*\).\(.\{10\}\)$/\1\4\3/
' data
```

where:

- `h`: saves entire line in hold space
- 1st `s`: extracts pos. 11-20
- 2nd `s`: swaps non-blank and blank blocks
- `y`: replaces spaces with 0s
- `x`: exchanges pattern and hold spaces
- `G`: appends newline and hold space to pattern space
- 3rd `s`: moves field to pos. 11-20; uncaptured `.` matches newline